# How to make long SED script leaner and more readable as code

Tags: xml, database, bash, sed, mediainfo

Here is the sed part of my script right now:

`sed -i -e 's/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g;s/<Duration_String4>/<inm:D-Duration>/g;s/<Width>/<inm:Width>/g;s/<\/Codec>/<\/inm:Video-codec>/g;s/<\/Duration_String4>/<\/inm:D-Duration>/g;s/<\/Width>/<\/inm:Width>/g;s/<FileExtension>/<inm:Wrapper>/g;s/<\/FileExtension>/<\/inm:Wrapper>/g' "$1"`

It's only going to get longer and longer. Is there a way to make this more readable as a piece of code? Can I have a new line for each replacement, or must I start a new sed command in order to do that?

Comment: Use an XML parser or take a look at sed's option `-f`.

Comment: Thank you. I've only started working with these scripts in the last few days. I think you're right. xmlstarlet looks like it could do what I want, but SED works well for me in the short term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First setup the sedstring in parts:

```
SEDSTR='s/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<Duration_String4>/<inm:D-Duration>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<Width>/<inm:Width>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<\/Codec>/<\/inm:Video-codec>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<\/Duration_String4>/<\/inm:D-Duration>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<\/Width>/<\/inm:Width>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<FileExtension>/<inm:Wrapper>/g'
SEDSTR="$SEDSTR;"'s/<\/FileExtension>/<\/inm:Wrapper>/g'

sed -i -e "$SEDSTR" "$1"
```

EDIT 1: Remark: Using shell-variables in lowercase is better.
EDIT 2: Appending can be done with `+=`

```
sedstr='s/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<Duration_String4>/<inm:D-Duration>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<Width>/<inm:Width>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<\/Codec>/<\/inm:Video-codec>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<\/Duration_String4>/<\/inm:D-Duration>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<\/Width>/<\/inm:Width>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<FileExtension>/<inm:Wrapper>/g'
sedstr+=';s/<\/FileExtension>/<\/inm:Wrapper>/g'

sed -i -e "${sedstr}" "$1"
```

Your next step might be making a function that will parse a configfile.
The configfile could have lines like

```
<Codec>*<inm:Video-codec>
</Codec>*</inm:Video-codec>
```

(with * a nice FieldSep) and let your function take care of the backslashes.

Or even better: tell your function is should always add an end-tag replacement,
and make a config file like

```
Codec/inm:Video-codec
Duration_String4/inm:D-Duration
Width/inm:Width
FileExtension/inm:Wrapper
```

Comment: Your first SEDSTR example is the only answer so far thatworked perfectly, and it looks very clean and will make my life easier. I don't understand your other suggestions but I really appreciate you posting them. I will look into them when I feel more comfortable with bash. I'm going to hold off on picking a correct answer for a little while, just in case some of the other posters get back to me re my comments.

Comment: Also, can you explain what's happening with the SEDSTRING? I don't see much on google about it. Is it just a variable that you're creating? How come you don't do SEDSTR="$SEDSTR; for the first line?

Comment: Btw: `a=abc; a+=123; echo $a`

Comment: @Tandy The SEDSTR is the random name of a variable we use here. I should have received the comment that it is cleaner to use lowercase for shell var's, so it wouldn't happen to be the same as internal var's. The first line just assigns a value to it. The next lines will append values by adding it to the value of the var (with a $ you ask for the value, without you assign).

Comment: When you feel more comfortable with bash, take a look at [Google's style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml).
When you want to continue with my example, you will find there something about functions and learn I should have made a local variabel with `local sedstr='s/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g'`.
For the future: You can read oldtag and newtag from a config file a generate the `s/<..>/<..>/g` and `s/<\/..>/<\/..>/` strings and append them to sedstr.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GNU awk equivalent:

```
awk -i inplace '{
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?Codec>/,"<\\1inm:Video-codec>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)Duration_String4>","<\\1inm:D-Duration>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)Width>","<\\1inm:Width>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)FileExtension>","<\\1inm:Wrapper>")
   print
}' "$1"
```

Comment: I like the look of that, very tidy. I copied and pasted your code directly to a .sh file and just added #!/bin/bash to the top. I got the following error  

`awk: unknown option -i ignored

awk: can't open file {
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?Codec>/,"<\\1inm:Video-codec>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)Duration_String4>","<\\1inm:D-Duration>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)Width>","<\\1inm:Width>")
   $0 = gensub(/<(\/?)FileExtension>","<\\1inm:Wrapper>")
   print
}
 source line number 1`

Comment: As I said, it uses gawk. You are apparently not using gawk (or maybe are using a very old version of it). Get a current gawk.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146955/) stating that

```
sed 's'/\
'[long1]'\
'[long2]'\
'/'\
'[long3]'\
'[long4]'\
'/' file.txt
```

"Splitting on several lines with backslash does work if new lines are not indented."

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `-e` multiple times:

```
sed -i -e 's/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g' \
       -e 's/<Duration_String4>/<inm:D-Duration>/g' \
       -e 's/<Width>/<inm:Width>/g' \
       -e 's/<\/Codec>/<\/inm:Video-codec>/g' \
       -e 's/<\/Duration_String4>/<\/inm:D-Duration>/g' \
       -e 's/<\/Width>/<\/inm:Width>/g' \
       -e 's/<FileExtension>/<inm:Wrapper>/g' \
       -e 's/<\/FileExtension>/<\/inm:Wrapper>/g' "$1"
```

which might lead you to refactor using `bash` arrays:

```
commands=(
       's/<Codec>/<inm:Video-codec>/g'
       's/<Duration_String4>/<inm:D-Duration>/g'
       's/<Width>/<inm:Width>/g'
       's/<\/Codec>/<\/inm:Video-codec>/g'
       's/<\/Duration_String4>/<\/inm:D-Duration>/g'
       's/<\/Width>/<\/inm:Width>/g'
       's/<FileExtension>/<inm:Wrapper>/g'
       's/<\/FileExtension>/<\/inm:Wrapper>/g'
)

for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
    options+=(-e "$cmd")
done

sed "${options[@]}" "$1"
```

Or, using the `-f` option and a process substitution:

```
sed -f <( printf "%s\n" "${commands[@]}" ) "$1"
```

Comment: I think your first example with the multiple -e looks great. It doesn't work for me though. I ran your script with abash shebang at the top. I get this error:   `sed: -e: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Tandy: Please check you do not have spaces after the last \ on each line.

Comment: You want spaces between the different options. Note the space between the last single and double quote in `options+="-e '$cmd' "`